# LWC: Trying to get Access token

Tags: lightning-web-components, callout, oauth2, accesstoken

I am trying to get an access token from parent salesforce org. Here is the code which I am using:

```
fetch('https://test-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                Headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body:{
                    grant_type : 'password',
                    client_id : 'clientID',
                    client_secret : 'clientSecretId',
                    username : 'myusername@mydomain.com', 
                    password : 'password+token'
                }
            })
            .then(response =>{
                alert(response.json());
            });
```

When I run this code I am getting the following error: Can someone tell me what mistake in my code.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the error message, you probably forget to configure the CORS (cross-origin resource sharing). You probably run your script on a different domain than the one you try to get the token from. Inside SF you have a CORS setting where you can declare that you authorize your domain to call the token one. Granularity is on sub-domain level.

Comment: Hi, @Bartheleway Thanks for your response. Yes, I have added the CORS setting has "https://*.my.salesforce.com". After adding also I am seeing this error message.

Comment: I know it's for test purpose but note that allowing that would make any Salesforce org to be able to call you ... Potentially a security threat. Have you a my domain registered ? Try to remove the wildcard and put the real complete host. Just for my understanding, you are writing a custom LWC which will be displayed inside SF and will display data from another SF org ? Are you sure there is no other way to achieve what you want ? For example external objects ? Make the calls from the backend using a named credential ?

Comment: hi @Bartheleway, The requirement is correct. From one SF instance to another SF instance I need to push the record. Currently, I am doing a POC but in real-time, the other system will be .net. I am doing POC to see how to push all the files and record in one button click from Salesforce to another System. For the POC I am using 2 salesforce instances to show the client a working demo.

Comment: Files and records are stored on Salesforce ? If yes, I would advise to switch in Apex and use a Named Credentials.

Comment: Yes, @Bartheleway Apex is my workaround and I have already started my work. I was trying to do all Javascript.